# How do I query the database for all the points that are within a certain radius from a users location?

Tags: django, google-maps, model, haversine

I am trying to get all the points from the database that are with a certain radius from the users location(e.g 10km). So basically I would like the  user to input a location, which would then be converted to lat and lng using the google maps api and have the application search for and return all the stores in the database that are within a 10 km radius of the users location. I have tried Haversines formula but can't seem to get that to work since I do not have a strong understanding of how to filter search results from the database. Could anyone please explain to me how best to query the database for results within a 10km radius using Haversines formula?

```
models.py:
class Detail(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    lat = models. DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=6)
    lng = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=6)

views.py:




def feed(request):
    latitude = request.session['lat']
    longitude = request.session['lng']
    radius = 20000
    unit = 6371 # Distance unit (kms)
    radius = float(radius) / 1000.0 # Distance radius convert m to km
    lat = float(latitude) # Central point latitude
    lng = float(longitude) # Central point longitude
    print(lat,lng,radius)
    limit = 1000
```

My views .py is returning to lng and lat of the users location but I don't know how to use that to search for stores within a certain radius.

Comment: Is there a reason why you do not use GeoDjango here? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/gis/

Comment: I considered geodjango but Haversines seemed like the faster option to implement between the two.Would geodjango be a better solution than using Haversines formula?